# Best way to handle animation with about 100 frames in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, html, animation

I need a page with a logo that animates that has about 100 frames. I was wondering if it's feasible to use the image swapping technique (changing the image every x seconds) or is it not recommended due to the number of frames? Is the next best alternative using a video? Just wanted to know which way is the best performance wise. Thanks!

Comment: It's also possible to make it a spritesheet and use a moving "viewing rectangle" to move through the frames. You could also try a GIF... :P

Comment: What frame rate do you need?  How big is the logo?  What is being animated?  Do you need alpha channel?

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. The logo will be on the front page and once it loads, it will redirect to the site. The logo animation has transparency, 15fps and is about 70MB in total for all frames. Is it feasible to have this file size in the first place? I worry about people who still have slow connection speeds.

Comment: Wow, 70MB. Is that when compressed? Do you have multiple frames that look the same to simulate a delay? In my opinion you should definitely try to take the file size down to at least 10mb. If you can't you should place the img in the bottom of your HTML and place it with CSS. That way, the logo will be the last thing to load. If course the logo isn't the most important thing on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I think `spritely` will be the best bet for you, due to short code and done.

## from the documentation:

`Spritely` is a simple plugin with only two key methods, `sprite()` and `pan()` both of which simply animate the background-image css property of an element. The difference between the two is that a `'sprite'` image contains two or more `'frames'` of animation, whereas a `'pan'` image contains a continuous image which pans left or right and then repeats. Typically, in either case, you would use a png file (with or without transparency) for this.

`You might wish to use a transparent gif for Internet Explorer 6`, though it probably won't look as good. Your html elements must already be the correct size you want the sprite to appear, but the background image will typically be larger than the html element, and the spritely methods reposition the background image within the html element.

they are using this image to animate:

[image]

and this is triggering code:

```
$('#bird').sprite({fps: 12, no_of_frames: 3});
```

To make the mouse attract the sprite when you click the screen, use this:

```
$('#bird').sprite({fps: 12, no_of_frames: 3}).activeOnClick().active();
$('body').flyToTap();
```

you can find more here: **http://www.spritely.net/documentation/**

Answer (score 0):

What browsers will you support? Is the image going to be transparent in some way?

If you will support the latest browsers only, you can use a sprite animation with a sprite image and [CSS3 Animation](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-animations/).

If you want to support all browsers and the image doesn't have to be transparent, you can just make a gif.

Then there's also two ways with javascript. One is the way you mention with swapping images, and one is like @MrXenotype says, that is using a sprited image. This one can be done in two ways. One by using the sprited image as a background-image and with JS change the background-position. The other one is like he says, move the sprited image layer in a "viewing rectangle".